# WordPress plugin activation, deactivation and uninstall hook not being triggered

Tags: hooks, oop, optimization

I am developing a WordPress plugin which requires certain rules to be added to the .htaccess file of the WordPress installation upon activation of the plugin.

Initially, before I switched my code to OOP (with classes and functions) the hooks and this functionality was working. But after I switched it, it doesn't work.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Optimizo', 'activation' ) );
```

The above code is how I am trying to call the function 'activation' from the class 'Optimizo' which resides in the same file as where I am writing the above activation hook. The 'activation' function has the necessary classes in it which should be called upon activation. Below is the content of the function.

```
protected function activation() {

    $this->activate();
}
```

I am just wondering if I wrote the code wrong of is it because that the function is having the protected access specifier or if I am doing something entirely wrong.

PS the function 'activate' resides in another class which is being extended to the 'Optimizo' class.

Answer (score 1):

The function needs to be public, but it can also be static.

For example, from the Akismet plugin:

In the plugin file:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Akismet', 'plugin_activation' ) );
```

In the Akismet class file:

```
public static function plugin_activation() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the function to 'public' from 'protected', but now I am getting the following error when I try to activate my plugin.

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context"

Also the function now looks like:

`public function activation() {

  $this->activate();
 }`

Comment: And the activate function is also public

`public function activate() {
 ...
 }`

Comment: @MinhazIrphan `$this` is not available inside the static method.

Comment: Yea, you can't use `$this` in a static function. You have to use the class name. In your case, this would be `Optimizo::activate();`

Comment: your callable references a static method, not a dynamic on, you would need to swap `Optimizo` for a variable instance of your class. Otherwise it would have to be static, and you'd need to change all the methods that function calls to static versions too

Comment: But NONE of my functions are static. Not even the 'activation' function which is called by the activation hook.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers, as @TomJNowell said, I changed the activation hook from 

`register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Optimizo', 'activation' ) );` 

to 

`register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $optimizo, 'activation' ) );`

And it seems to be working fine...